# R regression over columns with fixed deltas

Tags: r, regression

I have a data frame in R , df, where each row, X, is a subject (N= 100) and each column,S, the score for each subject on a task each month over the span of two years.  Thus i have a data frame of 100 subjects and 24 observations evenly spaced by 1 month intervals (ignoring month/day variance).

Question1: how do I fit a line (linear regression) to each subject?  I have trouble understanding how to do this over columns, as opposed to rows within a column.

Question2:  how do I fit a line (linear regression) to the whole data set?  I ask because I would like to segment the dataset into groups A and B (i.e. a column is labeled as condition: {A,B}), and fit a line to each subset of subject over the 24 timepoints.

apologies if this a simple question.

Comment: See `reshape2::melt` to get your data in a decent format. And share some data, and show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I constructed a dataset based on your description. If this is useful, perhaps include it in your question itself.

```
df<- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(1:24,100)+rnorm(2400),nrow=100,byrow=T))
names(df)<- paste("S",1:24,sep="")
df$ID<-1:100
df$group <- as.factor(sample(c("A","B"),100,replace=T))
```

Now melt your data frame to get the S1 to S24 columns as a factor variable.

```
library(reshape2)
m<- melt(df,id.vars=c("ID","group"))
```

Then you can use the following kind of call to examine a linear model of time for a particular ID.  You can use `lapply` to do this in one shot for all IDs.

```
summary(lm(value~as.numeric(variable), data=m, subset=ID==5))
```

And this will model all items as predicted by group. Note that the group factor is coerced to numeric. In this case A is 1 and B is 2.

```
summary(lm(value~group, data=m))
```

Comment: very helpful. apologies for not providing a sample, and appreciate your efforts here. I'll implement this and get back to you when i've had time to have a deep review of this. thanks!